# Why this Dockerfile have both ENV and export with the same PATH?

Tags: bash, sh, dockerfile

I was looking at the [golang:1.10.2 Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/golang/blob/329b6672949337c4469351b2e8b8575459a75c7f/1.10/stretch/Dockerfile) (as of today), and couldn't understand why the PATH variable is being used in two different places. Here's the bottom of the file with the pertinent snippet:

```
RUN set -eux; \
    # some code ...
    export PATH="/usr/local/go/bin:$PATH"; \
    go version

ENV GOPATH /go
ENV PATH $GOPATH/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:$PATH

RUN mkdir -p "$GOPATH/src" "$GOPATH/bin" && chmod -R 777 "$GOPATH"
WORKDIR $GOPATH
```

What is the purpose of

`export PATH="/usr/local/go/bin:$PATH";`

and

`ENV PATH $GOPATH/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:$PATH`

respectively?

My impression is that the `ENV` directive should be shortened to `ENV $GOPATH:$PATH` since `/usr/local/go/bin` is already in `$PATH`.

Comment: `export` is being run inside the RUN command, it has no bearing on the rest of the DockerFile

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thank you for the explanation. I can accept that as an answer.

Comment: @sargas, glad you found it helpful; moved from comment to an answer.

Comment: BTW, as an aside, `set -e` is not the always-a-good-idea equivalent to Perl's strict mode that many take it for. See [BashFAQ #105](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105) -- skipping the allegory for the exercises below if in a hurry -- for a discussion of some of the pitfalls; or https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/set-e/ for a comparison of places where its behavior differs across various shells (which should, perhaps, make it clear just how unreliable, surprising, and/or confusing-to-readers its behavior can be).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each `RUN` (when not in the explicit-argv usage mode) starts a new shell, which must exit before that RUN command is complete. That shell can only change its own environment and that of its children; it can't change the environment of other programs started after it exits.

By contrast, `ENV` controls the environment that Docker passes to future processes when they're started.

Thus, you could move the `ENV` above the `RUN` and remove the export from the `RUN` (to have the PATH correctly set before the shell is started), but you can't make a `RUN` do the work of a `ENV`.